# Function which returns max element of an input array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have some problems with solving the following task:

"Provide complete code of max() function which returns max element of an input array.
array - an input array of integer elements"

```
/*
* @name max - find max element of array
* @return - int - array element
*/

function max(array) {
  // Your code here...
}
```

Here is the way I provided, but it is incorrect. Please let me know what I missed. Hope for your help

```
function max(array) {
  let numsArr = [];

  while (true) {
    let num = prompt('Enter any number: ', '');

    if (num === '' || num === null) break;

    num = +num;
    numsArr.push(num);
  }

  return alert(Math.max(...numsArr));
}
```

Comment: You aren't answering the question. You never use the array passed in parameters. By *"input array"* they mean the one in the parenthesis `max(array)`

Comment: You have the `array` parameter and you are also getting a user input using `prompt()` and creating a new array. Which one do you want to use?

Comment: I've tested the given code and it works? The only problem is you're passing in an array and then not using it

Answer (score 3):

The instructions say

> "Provide complete code of max() function which returns max element of an input array. array - an input array of integer elements"

The *input* array sounds like the argument - it says nothing about `prompt`ing the user for inputs. Call `Math.max` on the input parameter instead:

```
const max = arr => Math.max(...arr);
```